# Full text search for irregular rapper names with Solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I'm implementing full text search functionality on [my rap website](http://rapgenius.com), and I'm running into some issues with rapper and song names.

For example, someone might want to search for the rapper "[Cam'ron](http://rapgenius.com/lyrics/Cam-ron/Killa-cam)" using the query "camron" (leaving out the mid-word apostrophe). Likewise, someone might search for the song "[3 Peat](http://rapgenius.com/lyrics/Lil-wayne/3-peat)" using the query "3peat".

"[The Notorious B.I.G.](http://rapgenius.com/lyrics/The-notorious-b-i-g/Party-and-bullshit)" is a bit of a weird case: "The Notorious BIG" and "The Notorious B.I.G." both work (I guess because the [solr.StandardFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StandardFilterFactory) removes dots from acronyms?), but "The Notorious B.I.G" (i.e., minus the trailing dot) doesn't.

Ideally all reasonable variations of these names should work. I'm guessing the answer has something to do with the [solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory), but I'm not sure.

Also, I'm using Sunspot with Rails if that's relevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You need to configure WordDelimiterFilterFactory properly. Try to enable all properties and don't forget to enable preserveOriginal property, which will save your original terms also.

**generateWordparts** - will make from *B.I.G.* terms - *B I G*

**generateNumberParts** - will make from *3Peat* terms - *3 Peat*

**catenateWords** - will make from *B.I.G.* terms - *BIG*

**catenateNumbers** - will make from *Rapper 802.11* terms - *Rapper 80211*

**catenateAll** - will make from *Rapper-802.11* term - *Rapper80211*

**splitOnCaseChange** - will make from *GanGsTa* terms - *Gan Gs Ta*

**preserveOriginal** - will save also original term. From *Rapper-802.11RuuLlZ* will make - *Rapper-802.11RuuLlZ*.

Comment: Great advice, thanks. I added the following to `schema.xml`: `<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" stemEnglishPossessive="1" splitOnNumerics="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>`. This seems to solve everything except the "B.I.G" case. Any ideas?

Comment: It can be because of StandardTokenizer. I would replace it with WhitespaceTokenizer instead. In order to analyse, how your analyzers are working, you can use "Analysis" in your solr, if you have web-interface for it. There you can see, which analyzer is transforming your text, and what is the result of it`s work.